# Why must I call viewWillAppear to get a cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When testing a UITableViewController subclass loaded from a storyboard cellForRowAtIndexPath will **return nil** unless I: A) send it viewWillAppear:YES or B) get tableView.numberOfSections.

**Why is this? Why doesn't accessing the view or sending the loadView selector on the main thread do the job?**

```
SpecBegin(CustomerViewController)
  describe(@"CustomerViewController", ^{

    __block CustomerViewController *_vc;

    beforeEach(^{
      NSLog(@"Before Each");
      UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_Pad" bundle:nil];
      _vc = (CustomerViewController *)[mainstoryboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customer"];
    });

    it(@"the first cell should be the fullName cell", ^{
      // Following line is needed to make the following tests pass.
      [_vc viewWillAppear:YES];
      UITableViewCell *cell = [_vc.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
      expect(cell.reuseIdentifier).to.equal(@"fullName");
    });

  });

SpecEnd
```

Comment: What's in your viewWillAppear method?  Is that method setting the data source of the table view, perhaps?

Comment: I'm not even sure what the code you posted means. What are the functions `describe`, `it`, and `expect`? What do they do?

Comment: @BlackRider He's trying to unit test UI. Ryan, I highly suggest testing your model, and not the UI that consumes it.

Comment: @ErikKerber If I'm using different cell types in different places shouldn't I test that it displays the right type at the right row?

Comment: @BlackRider That is syntactic sugar to help with TDD. https://github.com/specta/specta https://github.com/specta/expecta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that using the view controller method works but not the method directly on the table view object. There's no need to call `viewWillAppear` when you do it through the view controller.

This works:

```
[_vc tableView:_vc.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

This doesn't

```
[_vc.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Comment: So why not decouple your UITableViewDataSource from the controller then?

Comment: @ErikKerber Yes, that seems like the next logical step.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are unit testing UI code.  I would generally recommend against this, because you will be manually attempting to emulate ViewController lifecycle methods in order to *get close* to reproducing how your UI behaves in a running app.

I suggest trying 2 things instead:

1. Unit test your model/logic (as in, the data your table views are consuming).
2. If you must test your UI, I suggest looking into [Automated Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) with Xcode.

Comment: you are right in that if I were to test out the UI I would  be better served using UIAutomation or Calabash. What I'm doing is testing that I get the right return from a method on a class I've written. It turns out that the right way to do that is through the controller as you can see in my answer below.